# does itunes have an api to upload music through remote site?

Tags: itunes-store

i have a client who wants a his music artists to upload their music through the website. does itunes have an api that will alow these customers to upload their music to itunes through the website then have the music sold through the website, so that they dont have to go through itunes?

Answer (score 0):

[Tunecore](http://www.tunecore.com/) seems useful for this sort of task. They'll handle uploading to iTunes and a few other stores for a fee.

Apple doesn't provide an API for just anyone to upload whatever they like to the store.