# Using PHP to upload music files to iTunes

Tags: php, upload, itunes

How can I upload some music files to iTunes using PHP Code? I find api for search but nothing for uploading.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597224/does-itunes-have-an-api-to-upload-music-through-remote-site, though that question not specific about php it does still seem correct about no api being present. Also this seems best result in google bout this (i read all on first 2 pages from my search) https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3098876

Comment: http://deimos.apple.com/rsrc/doc/iTunesUAdministrationGuide/#AddingContent/chapter_12_section_6.html